# how i can convert string consisting of JSon Objects into array of Bson Documents?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

### I'm working on a task which is as the following :

User Management Project

You are required to create a .Net Core 2.2 Web API with MongoDB

The project loads list of users on project load from external source and stores them in the DB in "Users" collection.
Source: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

You need to provide the ability to Add new user to the same collection, update and delete by Id.

You need to provide the ability to search Users by the following filters on the same function (POST Method).
- Search By name
- Search By username
- Search By address.zipcode
- search By company.name
You can have multiple search filters at the same time.
Search response returns list of users matching the filter criteria.

All API Methods should be authenticated using username and password in the request header.

### Expose the Web API using swagger.

i want to load the data from external api and store it at once into the MongoDB any know how i can do this ?
thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  This site is not a code writing service.  You will need to show us what you've researched and tried already.  Consider reading this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This looks like an interview question, I can assure you no one here will assist you cheating your way into employment.